# Matlab: Index for 5 x 5 grid points

Tags: matlab, indexing

For the following:

```
    x = [0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5];

    for k = 1:1:5
      plot(x(k),x','b^','linewidth', 2)
      hold on
    end
```

similar to:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0.5:1:4.5);
```

How can i index each point (blue triangles) coordinates?

[image]

Outcome should be like this:

```
point1  = [x(1),x(1)]; % [0.5,0.5]
point2  = [x(1),x(2)]; % [0.5,1.5]
point3  = [x(1),x(3)]; % [0.5,2.5]
point4  = [x(1),x(4)]; % [0.5,3.5]
point5  = [x(1),x(5)]; % [0.5,4.5]
point6  = [x(2),x(1)]; % [1.5,0.5]
...
point25  = [x(5),x(5)];% [4.5,4.5]
```

I must do something wrong or matlab program isnt letting me index these today.

```
[~,idx] = length(point(:));
idxpoint = ind2sub(size(point),idx);
```

Please write a working example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your question. A totally blind guess without fully understanding your problem I would say you should look into reshape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. You can use `meshgrid` for that:

```
x = linspace(0.5, 4.5, 5);
y = linspace(0.5, 4.5, 5);
[Y, X] = meshgrid(x, y);

points = [X(:) Y(:)];
```

This method has the advantage that you can use different `linspace` for x and y coordinates.

Now every row of `points` stores x and y coordinates one point:

```
points(1,:)
ans =

0.5000
0.5000

points(25,:)
ans =

4.5000
4.5000
```

Comment: Educative as always, be well @angainor.

Answer (score 1):

You can stack all of your points into an N-by-2 matrix, with each row representing a point"

```
close all
x = [0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5];
n = length(x);
X = [];

for k = 1:1:5
    plot(x(k),x','b^','linewidth', 2)
    X = [X; repmat(x(k),n,1) x'];
    hold on
end

% replot on new figure
figure, hold on
plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'b^','linewidth',2)

% Each row of X is one of your points, i.e.
% Point number 5:
X(5,:)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
[x y] = meshgrid(.5:1:4.5);
points = [reshape(x,1,[])',reshape(y,1,[])']


points =

0.5000    0.5000
0.5000    1.5000
0.5000    2.5000
0.5000    3.5000
0.5000    4.5000
1.5000    0.5000
1.5000    1.5000
1.5000    2.5000
1.5000    3.5000
1.5000    4.5000
2.5000    0.5000
2.5000    1.5000
2.5000    2.5000
2.5000    3.5000
2.5000    4.5000
3.5000    0.5000
3.5000    1.5000
3.5000    2.5000
3.5000    3.5000
3.5000    4.5000
4.5000    0.5000
4.5000    1.5000
4.5000    2.5000
4.5000    3.5000
4.5000    4.5000
```